# The small concrete category $C = (\mathbb{Z_2}, +)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories, groupoids

I'm grappling with the question of viewing a group as a category, which as I understand it means that if $(G,+)$ is the group in question, then the group can also be thought of as a small concrete category $C$ in which ${\rm Ob}(C) =\{ \bullet \}$ and ${\rm Hom}(C,C)$ is just the elements of $G$.

But that's still pretty vague, so I'm trying to construct the specific category $C=(\mathbb{Z_2},+)$, i.e., the integers modulo $2$ under plus, but viewed as a category. What I have so far is that ${\rm Ob}(C) =\{ \bullet \}$ and ${\rm Hom}(C,C)=\{0,1\}$ where $0$ is the identity morphism so that whatever $1$ is (and that part isn't really clear yet), $0 \circ 0 =0 $ and $ 0 \circ 1 = 1 \circ 0 = 1.$ So far, so good. For this category to properly mimic the group, it must be the case that $1 \circ 1=0$.

So can I just define $1$ as a morphism that is an its own inverse? If not, what would be the next step?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define composition of morphisms as you like, as long as they satisfy the correct axioms.

Notice that in your case ($G=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$) you don't even have to specify this: if you see $G$ as a category with one object (a *monoid*), all your morphisms will have to be isomorphisms (so that your only hom-set behaves just like the group).
If you have only two morphisms $\{0,1\}$, and $0$ is the identity, what will the inverse of $1$ be?

(Of course, you could also define $1\circ 1$ to be $1$; but as such it wouldn't be an isomorphism, and your monoid wouldn't represent a group anymore.
Conversely, $1\circ0=1=0\circ1$ are forced by the identity axiom.)